# Is there a concept of path when a div changes its location?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

The code below has a `div` which "moves" between two container `div` when clicked

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    left: true
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="element" v-if="left" v-on:click="left=!left">element</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="element" v-if="!left" v-on:click="left=!left">element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is there a concept of path when such an element (with the same`id`) changes its location in the rendered DOM?** If so: is there a way to visualize its transition from one place to another (via a slide on this path)?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to your question is no. You could fade-out and fade-in, but if you want a movement transition, you need to change position attributes on an element, rather than reparenting it.

Comment: How should this look like? Is it OK like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/9t2btpvs/)? If that's what you're looking for I can add an answer and give some details how I've created it. But as mentioned by Roy it's probably easier to create one element and change it's position on click. Like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/741wk6d0/). I think this is looking better because color change is also animated. Or are the two elements with different content?

Comment: @AWolf: thanks a lot for the fiddles - they would make a great answer. The second one fits my bill (I will have a close look tomorrow). What I want to do is to have two groups of tags filtering a list of articles (one group "show articles with these tags", and the second one "do not show ..."). The filtering and tag switching works, (my code example is a simplification of what I actually encoded). I just feel that when clicking on a tag, its apparition the other group is too abrupt, I would prefer to have it sliding from one group to the other - something the 2nd fiddle seems to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks for better explaining me your use-case. Now it's clearer what you need.

Please have a look at the modified demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/s0w4qabr/).

In the demo I've added two sliders and the filtering as I've understood how it should work. One "self-coded" slider and one using [Vue-js-toggle-button](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button) dependency.

I think both will work for you but I would probably use the library as it reduces your code and styling.

**So how is it working?**

I'm using a transition animation called `animation` with `transition: all 0.5s ease;` and two classes:

- `left-position` class for green background color and `margin-left: 0` to have the element on the left side of the container
- `right-position` class with red background and `margin-left: calc(75% - 20px);` for the right position. The `-20px` is because of the padding that I've added and 75% because the element is 25% wide to have a margin that is pushing the element to the right edge.

By toggling the `include` property the animation is triggered and the margin change will be animated.

**Issues that I've detected in my demo**

- The two sliders can get out of sync - toggling the bottom slider toggles both sliders but toggling the other one it won't toggle the library slider. Not sure, what's wrong here but just to mention it and if you're using only one it won't be a problem.
- List transition looks a bit strange sometimes - if items are removed because of a filter change they appear and are getting faded out.

**Note**

The tagging input in the demo is pretty basic and I would use a library for this but as this is not the problem I think it's OK for the demo.

```js
Vue.use(window['vue-js-toggle-button'].default)

new Vue({
  el: "#container",
/*  components: {
   toggleButton: window['vue-js-toggle-button']
  },*/
  data: {
    include: true,
    filterTags: 'even odd',
    articles: [{
     id: 0,
     title: 'Test0',
      tags: ['even']
    },
    {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Test1',
      tags: ['odd']
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     title: 'Test2',
      tags: ['even']
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     title: 'Test3',
      tags: ['odd']
    },
    {
     id: 4, // just to test even & odd exluding
     title: 'Test4',
      tags: ['no number']
    }
    
   ]
  },
  computed: {
   filtered () {
     return this.articles.filter((article) => 
       article.tags.some((tag) => 
        {
          let result = this.filterTags && this.filterTags.indexOf(tag) !== -1
          return this.include ? result: !result;
       })
      )
    }
  },
  methods: {
   updateFilterInclude ({value}) {
     console.log(value)
      this.include = value
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.vue-js-switch#changed-font {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.animation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.left-position {
  background-color: green;
  /*transform: translate(0, 0);*/
  margin-left: 0;
 }

.right-position {
  background: red;
  /*transform: translate(100%, 0);*/
  margin-left: calc(75% - 20px);
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
  padding: 5px;
}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.element {
  width: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button/master/dist/index.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Filter tags<input v-model="filterTags"/>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="element animation" @click="include = !include" :class="{'left-position': include, 'right-position': !include}">
      {{include ? 'include' : 'exlude'}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <toggle-button
      id="changed-font"
      :width="200"             
      :height="40"
      :color="{checked: 'green', unchecked: 'red'}"
      :labels="{checked: 'include', unchecked: 'exclude'}" :value="include" @change="updateFilterInclude"> {{include ? 'include' : 'exlude'}}</toggle-button>
    <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
      <li v-for="article in filtered" :key="article">
        {{article.tags.join(' ')}} - {{article.title}}
      </li>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I was not clear in my description. A screenshot is here: i.imgur.com/WKzR76z.png. The arrow is the "path" I was mentioning (currently clicking on "hello" immediately moves it to the "do not show ..." box - I wanted to add a notion of slide so that the user is more aware of the fact that it moved (he may not notice otherwise, especially with more tags)).

Comment: OK, I see. That seems to be a bit more complicated because you have to add a transition to each tag that you've clicked. I'll check this later today. But for now I've created a basic fiddle where just the animation is missing. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cf0jknu9/). It's my first try with-out modifying the library but I think a change of `vue-input-tag` code is required to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

A simple script which animates a div moving from an origin to a destination:

```js
move( document.querySelector("#element"),  document.querySelector("#destination") ); 

function move( element, destination){

  var destinationElement= element.cloneNode(true);//https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode
  
  destinationElement.style.visibility= "hidden";
  destination.appendChild( destinationElement );
  
  animate( element, destinationElement );
  
  
}

//it could be better to use jquery animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
function animate( element, destination, step ){
  
  if( !step ) 
    step= 0;
    
  var steps= 100;
  var origin= element.getBoundingClientRect();
  element.style.position= "absolute";
  element.style.top= ( origin.top * ( (steps - step ) / steps ) + 
                     destination.getBoundingClientRect().top * (  step / steps ) ) + "px";
  element.style.left= ( origin.left * ( (steps - step ) / steps ) + 
                     destination.getBoundingClientRect().left * (  step / steps ) ) + "px";

  if( step < steps ){
    setTimeout( function(){
      animate(element, destination, ++step );
    },50);
  }else{
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    destination.style.visibility= "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
#origin{
  width: 60px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
#destination{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  top: -50px;
  left:200px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

#element{
  
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="origin">
  <div id="element">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="destination">
</div>
```